# Определение ошибок в консоли

Tags: python-3.x, консоль, обработка-ошибок

Есть готовая программа в режиме теста. Допустим, во время эксплуатации возникает ошибка, и она аварийно завершается, а мне очень нужно увидеть, в чем заключается ошибка. Можно ли с помощью стандартных средств Python реализовать остановку программы, а не её завершение? (Программа с текстовым интерфейсом на Python 3.7.0)

Comment: вы хотите, чтобы в отладчик программа упала в случае возникновения ошибки? Что вы подразумеваете под "остановку программы, а не её завершение" опишите как это выглядит подробно.

Comment: @jfs В том и есть проблема, что я не знаю как это должно выглядеть и чем реализуется. Как-нибудь остановить программу - один из методов решения. В конце концов мне не важно, каким будет решение, важно, чтобы в итоге в консоли я мог видеть текст ошибки, а это невозможно при её стандартном поведении(сразу же закрывается)

Comment: то есть вы просто хотите, чтобы консоль осталась висеть при возникновении исключения? Самый простой вариант: запускайте из существующей консоли.

Comment: Это хороший вариант, однако неюзабельный для рядового пользователя, что мне как автору программы не идет плюсом в зачет. Тем, не менее, попробую что-нибудь и с этим

Comment: что "неюзабельного" в том что консольная программа из консоли запускается? "Рядовому пользователю" traceback в любом случае слабо поможет¶ Чтобы обычные исключения перехватить и выполнить какие-то свои действия, к примеру в лог/файл текст ошибки записать, можно `sys.excepthook` определить  и/или просто try/except на верхнем уровне добавить. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6234405/4279 Чтобы в интерактивную консоль получить после окончания скрипта, можно `-i` флаг Питону передать в командной строчке. Всё зависит от того что вы хотите на самом деле получить.